# how to distinguish slot in multiple levels of pure functions in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

For example, I may have

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} // Select[#1, ((*** + 1 &) > 2) &] &
```

Here, `***` also wants to be #1, but not recognized as the outmost layer's #1. Is there any way to distinguish the two?

Thanks.

Comment: The question will be easier to understand if you post your desired result

Comment: Two good answers there. @Leo answered what normally goes wrong with nested anonymous functions. @Timo realized what went wrong in Qiang Li's particular bit of code.

Comment: Is the code snippet you posted equivalent to `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} // Select[#1, # > 1 &] &`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question.  What is your expected output?..  {2,3,4,5}?...  If so, there's no logical confusion between slots: every element in the list that's the first argument of `Select` will be fed into a function (the second argument).  The following works just fine:

`{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} // Select[#, ((# + 1) > 2) &] &`

In case there ever arises a conflict, instead of slot/ampersand notation, you can use `Function[{x,y,...},...]` notation, e.g.

`{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} // Select[#, Function[{x}, (x + 1) > 2]] &`

Comment: I should also add that using Function[] notation can generally help you sort out your anonymous function in case you get confused.  For example, your original `((# + 1&) > 2)&` (which, as Timo points out, doesn't make sense) would be equivalent to 
`Function[{x}, Function[{y}, (y + 1)] > 2]]`; with this notation the mistake is (hopefully) easier to see.

Answer (score 3):

You have one too many ampersands in your code, try

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} // Select[#1, ((# + 1) > 2) &] &
```

This way `#1` picks up an element from the list and passes it to the comparison test function. So in effect `#1` and `#` do get the same element.

It makes no real sense to have `((# + 1&) > 2)&` as a comparison function since the outer function cannot pass it's arguments on. You have effectively written `(F > 2)&`, and even though F is a pure function there is no slot for it's arguments. For your way to work you'd have to write `((# + 1&[#]) > 2)&`, which equates to `(F[#] > 2)&`.